# What does "cleanup" in NEXT_INST_F and NEXT_INST_V mean?

Tags: tcl

I am plowing TCL source code and get confused at macro NEXT_INST_F and NEXT_INST_V in tclExecute.c. Specifically the `cleanup` parameter of the macro.

Initially I thought `cleanup` means the net number of slots consumed/popped from the stack, e.g. when 3 objects are popped out and 1 object pushed in, cleanup is 2.

But I see `INST_LOAD_STK` has `cleanup` set to 1, shouldn't it be zero since one object is popped out and 1 object is pushed in?

I am lost reading the code of NEXT_INST_F and NEXT_INST_V, there are too many jumps.

Hope you can clarify the semantic of `cleanup` for me.

Comment: Mmmh. I am certainly not an authority here, but where do you see 1 pop/ 1 push in `INST_LOAD_STK`. I see one peek (OBJ_AT_TOS, for the variable name) and then one pop (NEXT_INST_V with cleanup = 1), once loading of the variable is done (or failed). Seems good to me and in line with the interpretation of `cleanup`: `how many objects to remove from the stack`.

Answer (score 0):

The `NEXT_INST_F` and `NEXT_INST_V` macros (in the implementation of Tcl's bytecode engine) clean up the state of the operand stack and push the result of the operation before going to the next instruction. The only practical difference between the two is that one is designed to be highly efficient when the number of stack locations to be cleaned up is a constant number (from a small range: 0, 1 and 2 — this is the overwhelming majority of cases), and the other is less efficient but can handle a variable number of locations to clean up or a number outside the small range. So `NEXT_INST_F` is basically an optimised version of `NEXT_INST_V`.

The place where macros are declared in tclExecute.c has this to say about them:

```c
/*
 * The new macro for ending an instruction; note that a reasonable C-optimiser
 * will resolve all branches at compile time. (result) is always a constant;
 * the macro NEXT_INST_F handles constant (nCleanup), NEXT_INST_V is resolved
 * at runtime for variable (nCleanup).
 *
 * ARGUMENTS:
 *    pcAdjustment: how much to increment pc
 *    nCleanup: how many objects to remove from the stack
 *    resultHandling: 0 indicates no object should be pushed on the stack;
 *      otherwise, push objResultPtr. If (result < 0), objResultPtr already
 *      has the correct reference count.
 *
 * We use the new compile-time assertions to check that nCleanup is constant
 * and within range.
 */
```

*However,* instructions can also directly manipulate the stack. This complicates things quite a lot. *Most* don't, but that's not the same as all. If you were to view this particular load of code as one enormous pile of special cases, you'd not be very wrong.

---

`INST_LOAD_STK` (a.k.a `loadStk` if you're reading disassembly of some Tcl code) is an operation that will pop an unparsed variable name from the stack and push the value read from the variable with that name. (Or an error will be thrown.) It is totally expected to pop one value and push another (from `objResultPtr`) since we are popping (and decrementing the reference count) of the variable name value, and pushing and incrementing the reference count of a different value that was read from the variable.

The code to read and write variables is among the most twisty in the bytecode engine. Far more `goto` than is good for your health.